# Update Only Rows with Shared/Similar Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OK - I have a simple table - below - what I am trying to do is to identify only those rows that have a shared value - so anything that has a shared "apc" value - DO x else Do Y

```
CREATE TABLE #test (hcpcs varchar(10), apc varchar(100), rate money) 

INSERT INTO #test (hcpcs, apc)
SELECT '97110', '8009'
UNION ALL
SELECT '71020', '8009'
UNION ALL
SELECT '85025', '8006'
```

So - from the above - all those rows that share "8009" - I will gram those rows for an update - they will share the same "rate". Row with "8006" will not be a part of that update

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
     FROM #test t2
     WHERE t2.apc = #test.apc
     AND t2.hcpcs != #test.hcpcs)
```

Make sure `apc` is indexed so that this can be done effectively.

Comment: Where has OP mentioned that `hcpcs` must be different?

Comment: On the assumption that tables shouldn't have rows which are completely identical, `hcpcs` appears to be a differentiating column, and able to cater for the fact that there is a different row with the same `apc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE with `Count(*) over ( Partition By apc)`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT t.hcpcs, t.apc, t.rate,
         count_apc = Count(*) over ( Partition By t.apc)
  FROM Test t
)
SELECT hcpcs, apc, rate
FROM cte 
WHERE count_apc > 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78299/9/0)</kbd>

You can simply replace the `Select` with an `Update CTE`, actually you'll update the table `Test`.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78299/8/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below, where the inner query will get you the `apc` which has been repeated.
`group by apc` will group the rows by apc and get the apc which has more than 1 occurrence.

```
update #test
set rate = someval
where apc in ( 
select apc from #test
group by apc
having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    distinct
    apc,
    countAPC = count(apc) over(partition by apc)
into
    #testShared
from 
    #test

update #test 
set 
    rate = 2
where
    apc = (select apc from #testShared where countAPC > 1)
```