# Update Only Rows With Shared/Similar Value

Tags: sql-server, sql

OK - I have a simple table - below - what I am trying to do is to identify only those rows that have a shared value - so anything that has a shared "apc" value - DO x else Do Y

```
CREATE TABLE #test (hcpcs varchar(10), apc varchar(100), rate money) 

INSERT INTO #test (hcpcs, apc)
SELECT '97110', '8009'
UNION ALL
SELECT '71020', '8009'
UNION ALL
SELECT '85025', '8006'
```

So - from the above - all those rows that share "8009" - I will gram those rows for an update - they will share the same "rate".  Row with "8006" will not be a part of that update

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Did it not work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Only Rows with Shared/Similar Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769075/update-only-rows-with-shared-similar-values)

Comment: Hmpf..should read comments then i could have saved myself the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
     FROM #test t2
     WHERE t2.apc = #test.apc
     AND t2.hcpcs != #test.hcpcs)
```

Make sure `apc` is indexed so that this can be done effectively.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the most comfortable way to get all desired results is using SQL-Server's OVER Klause.

```
select *, count(*) over (partition by apc) as CNT
from #test order by CNT desc
```

will return all rows along with the duplicate information (order clause is just used so you can easily very this).

To turn this into an update, I'd use a CTE:

```
with T1 as (select hcpcs, count(*) over (partition by apc) as CNT
    from #test)
update #test
set rate=@newrate
from #test inner join t1 on #test.hcpcs=T1.hcpcs
where CNT > 1
```

(please note that the order by clause had to vanish - it's not allowed in CTE and would be useless anyway :))

Answer (score 0):

Just change whatever you want to the CASE expression. You can use the OUTPUT clause to check what it does, then remove it in the actual query.

```
UPDATE T 
SET rate = CASE WHEN SRC.CNT > 1 THEN rate*5.00 ELSE rate*2.00 END
OUTPUT inserted.apc, deleted.rate old_rate, inserted.rate NEW_rate -- This is just to show results for testing
FROM #test T
JOIN (SELECT apc, COUNT(*) CNT
     FROM #test
     GROUP BY apc) SRC ON SRC.apc = T.apc
```